# How to send POST request in Java/Android without any params?

Tags: java, android

This is my code that I usually use to send POST requests to the API:

```
if (method == "POST") {
    // request method is POST
    // defaultHttpClient

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));


    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
}
```

So far so good, but now there is this new API call that should be POST but have no params
so If I pass `NULL` as params I get a null pointer exception and there is no new `UrlEncodedFormEntity()` constructor that takes no parameters, so what do I do?

Comment: have you tried if you can skip the entire `httpPost.setEntity(...` line? (You don't have an entitiy to send)

Comment: Yeah, that worked, thanks!!! If you post this as the answer, Id accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have an entity to send in a POST, skip the command that adds one.

```
if (method == "POST") {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    if (params != null)
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
     // else - just nothing

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
}
```